# Is my express my task clearly by using "a successive polyline"?

Tags: meaning

i am asking for help in this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/52456/74719)

> Is there a way (like planning algorithms) to draw a successive   polyline to
>   fill a specific shape (like triangle)?

i am concerned about if i express my task clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The word "successive" is confusing.

"Successive" is usually used for a sequence of distinct things.  For example, Ukrainian nesting dolls can be opened up one-by-one, revealing successively smaller dolls.

Theoretically, a polyline has zero-width.  In your application, you need to apply a width to the polyline, in order to fill the area of the shape.  You also need to specify how the corners are shaped:  Do they expand to arcs of circles, or do they expand to sharp corners, or are the line segments implemented as rectangles that do not extend beyond the corners?  The documentation for the Java Swing graphics library discusses this issue as part of explaining the parameters for line styles.